# Add a series as a column in R

Tags: r

I need to expand a dataset and merge with series of time from 1 hr to 600 hr

```
ID   Age   Weight
1     25     150
2     30     140 
3     28     170
```

to the following format [dots represent continuous count from 4 to 599; with the same ID, Age and Weight values]

```
ID   Age   Weight  Time
1     25     150    1
1     25     150    2
1     25     150    3
1     25     150    4
..    ..     ...   .. 
1     25     150   599
1     25     150   600
2     30     140    1
2     30     140    2
2     30     140    3 
2     30     140    4
..    ..     ...    ..  
2     30     140    599
2     30     140    600
3     28     170     1
3     28     170     2
3     28     170     3
3     28     170     4
..    ..     ...    ..
3     28     170     599
3     28     170     600
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = 1) %>%
  group_by(ID, Age, Weight) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Time = 1:600)

#      ID   Age Weight  Time
#   <int> <int>  <int> <dbl>
# 1     1    25    150     1
# 2     1    25    150     2
# 3     1    25    150     3
# 4     1    25    150     4
# 5     1    25    150     5
# 6     1    25    150     6
# 7     1    25    150     7
# 8     1    25    150     8
# 9     1    25    150     9
#10     1    25    150    10
# … with 1,790 more rows
```

---

Or in base R using `split` and `transform`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) transform(x, Time = 1:600)))
```

Comment: Isn't this simply a problem for `expand.grid`?

Comment: Probably it can be solved with `expand.grid` as well.

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thank you very much. What is I want to add time from 1 to 600 hour but every 0.1 hour instead of every hour?

Comment: @AmirYoussef Your expected output doesn't show that. Do you mean `df %>%
  mutate(Time = 1) %>%
  group_by(ID, Age, Weight) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Time = seq(1, 600, 0.1))` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, You provided the right solution for my original question. I was asking about a different case in my comment. This also worked. Thank you very much.